# jquery sortable - how to prevent item from dragging from one list to another

Tags: jquery-ui

There are two sortable UL elements which are linked to each other via 'connectWith' options so that items from one list can be moved to another list and vice versa. I'm in need to prohibit from moving/dragging some items to another list while still letting them to be draggable within their own list. Is there any way to implement such behavior?

For now I can only restrict items from dragging using 'items' option of those sortable lists but while this prevents the desired items from dragging to another list this also prevents those items from dragging within their own lists (which is bad).

Comment: can you paste the current code so we know what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to get around this is by using the `li` elements `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events. When the mouse is clicked, I changed my CSS class (or whatever else) so that it falls out of the items list.